# Fragment overlap another when go back

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

i have menu with two fragments. when i choose second fragment, i can move to third fragment with button.

**MainActivity**

```
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close);
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("demo");

    mSelectedId = savedInstanceState == null ? R.id.aboutConference : savedInstanceState.getInt("SELECTED_ID");
    itemSelection(mSelectedId);

}

private void setToolbar() {
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
}

private void initView() {
    mDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_drawer);
    mDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
}

private void itemSelection(int mSelectedId) {


    switch (mSelectedId) {

        case R.id.aboutConference:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new FirstFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            break;


        case R.id.aboutDeveloper:
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new SecondFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;

    }

}
```

**Second fragment**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_fragment, container, false);

        Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new ThirdFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

When i press backbutton, it's working correctly.

[second fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGOsG.png)

But if i move to third fragment, choose first fragment in menu and press backbutton, third fragment overlaps first fragment

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRs5K.png)

How i can resolve this problem?

**UPDATE: i don't want that i can return from first fragment to third when i press back button.**

Comment: setBackground in parent tag of xml layout of each fragment. Preferably with white color.

Comment: set your framelayout background in white color

Comment: i don't want that i can return from first fragment to third when i press back button.

Answer (score 0):

As `Shaishav` and `vishal` told you need to put `color`to your parent view of the fragment.

orelse you need to `Override` the `onBackButton` pressed method and make sure the remove the previous item from stack.

To check if item is there in the stack or not try the following code

```
fragmentManager1.getBackStackEntryCount()
```